# Issues with update hook in drupal 6

Tags: hooks, entities

I have this purchase module defined. And I have implemented the update hook something like this

```
<?php
  function purchase_update($node) {
    echo 'Updating';
    exit(0);
  }

  function purchase_help($path, $arg) {
    $output = ''; 
    switch ($path) {
      case "admin/help#purchase":
        $output = '<p>'.  t("Update help") .'</p>';
        break;
    }
    return $output;
  }
```

However, whenever I edit a node of type purchase, it doesn't call my update function. Any suggestions what could go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the purchase-module create and implement the entire purchase node type or did you create that in the admin system?

If you created it in the admin-system you can't use those functions. They are for node type modules (a rarer and rarer kind of module use these days).

You probably want hook_nodeapi. It's a common misconception.
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6

```
function hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'update':
      if($node->type == 'purchase') {
        echo 'Updating';
        exit(0);
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Although I feel drupal has been way unmanaged. If I need to find something, there is lot of hassle. I used to use drupal up to 6, then I felt it's not good for enterprise application. So I didn't go beyond. Now for small applications, I still use it, but version 6 and it's terrible to get support

Comment: Drupal 6 is a very useful CMS and framework but it is far from perfect. Drupal 7 improves a lot on it. Drupal 8 is coming up and it has even further improvements.

People are making a tremendous effort to document and extend Drupal. It is a lot to take in and the learning curve is quite steep.

I find Django easier to learn but I've done really nice things with Drupal.